# "It is remains the" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was reading an article and found something similar to the following:

> **It is remains the** highest-grossing war film of all time

I would have written the same as:

> **It remains the** highest-grossing war of all times

Is "It is remains the" even correct? If yes, why? I have found several articles using it and I find it odd.

I can find several articles using it. For instance, the following

**Forbes:**

> It **is remains the** fifth biggest grossing movie of all time in America, with just a day (or two at worst) to go before surpassing the $623m gross of The Avengers.

**AutoExpress:**

> The P50 **is remains the** only production vehicle ever built on the Isle of Man, and is also in contention for the smallest car ever built.

**Independent:**

> Although the Victory Front has been keen to point out that **is remains the** “major political force” in the country

**A report from the UK parliament:**

> Stigmatism **is remains the** greatest barrier to successful appeal and challenge.

Maybe someone made a mistake and it was copied everywhere. I was just wondering, how misleading such typographical errors (from various established sources) would be for non-native speakers.

Comment: All of those are editing errors (the writers changed their minds, and forgot to delete the "is"), except the Independent quote: that is a typo ("is" for "it").

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's a mistake. You can find all sorts of ungrammatical structures by Googling. The most logical explanation to me is that the authors wanted to say "is", but then changed their mind and used "remains" forgetting to delete the "is".